# Loop through NodeList: Array.prototype.forEach.call() vs Array.from().forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, prototype, nodelist

So I want an easy way to loop through nodelists, and I always hated that I can't use `forEach` on nodeLists.

So, now I do: `Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodeList, callback)`.

and for index, i do: `Array.prototype.indexOf.call(nodeList, node)`.

and for pretty much everything I use Array.prototype on nodeLists.

But I'm wondering if these are considered hacks?

Are they the right way to do it?

Also, assuming I don't actually need an array from nodeList, is there an advantage of using `Array.from(nodeList).forEach(callback)` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodeList, callback)` will apply the logic of `forEach` on the node list. `forEach` just have a `for` loop in it that goes from index `0` to `this.length` and calling a callback on each of the items. This method is calling `forEach` passing the node list as its `this` value, since node lists have similar properties of an array (`length` and `0`, `1`, ...), everything works fine.

`Array.from(nodeList).forEach(callback)` will create a new array from the node list, then use `forEach` on that new array. This second method could be split into two self explanatory lines:

```
var newArray = Array.from(nodeList);  // create a new array out of the node list
newArray.forEach(callback);           // call forEach on the new array
```

The first approach is better because it doesn't create additional uneeded resources and it work on node lists directly.

Comment: "The first approach is better because it doesn't create additional uneeded resources and it work on node lists directly!" any perf tests to prove this claim?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko [**`Function.prototype.call`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) says _...calls a function with a given this value..._ thus the node list is passed as `this` itself! And [**`Array.from`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) says _...creates a new Array instance from an array-like or iterable object_!

Comment: And? How do you know using dynamic context when calling `.forEach` doesn't result in some sort of de-optimization? There is nothing "obvious!" when it comes to performance. I mean your claim that "the first approach is better" not the underlying machinery.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Well one can easely observe that the first method is only looping once! The second however is looping twice (one loop for creating a new array out of the node list, the second is when calling `forEach` on the node list)! So the first method is much more optimized than the second (specially for large node lists or any array-like objects)!

Comment: Can you prove it with test? Using exclamation marks doesn't prove anything.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko The time that the second method takes is almost twice the time that the first method is taking: https://jsfiddle.net/wtz90wb3/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Your tests were measuring dom operation performance. https://jsfiddle.net/3L6967vz/ The results are not that stable and obvious. Keep calm and do perf test before making claims. "VM1007:62 forEach: 14.3ms
2017-04-17 14:41:50.550 VM1007:66 from: 22.4ms
2017-04-17 14:41:50.575 VM1007:70 from with cb: 23.6ms"
vs "forEach: 18.5ms
2017-04-17 14:41:54.436 VM1007:66 from: 15.2ms
2017-04-17 14:41:54.450 VM1007:70 from with cb: 14.2ms"

Comment: @YuryTarabanko and one thing you should observe, node lists contain objects so the copy using `Array.from` won't take much time as it doesn't clone the object it's just copy their references. If the array-like object contains basic types such as string which necessitate copying then the gap between the first and the second method quiet big performence-wise! https://jsfiddle.net/37bt902o/!

Comment: And BTW I'm not arguing that the first method might be faster. I am just trying to convince you that such a claims should only be made based on tests. Both operations have the same Big-O. So you can't simply tell which one is faster using only your imagination and exclamation marks.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko It's clear as the sun that the first is faster than the second! You just don't see it! Sometimes it is obvious which is optimized without the need for tests.

Answer (score 4):

The first method is ES5 compatible:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodeList, callback).
```

The second method uses `Array.from` which was only defined in ES6:

```
Array.from(nodeList).forEach(callback)
```

However, you are not optimising the use of `Array.from` here, because you first create the whole array, and then iterate over it with `forEach`.

Instead use the second argument of `Array.from`:

```
Array.from(nodeList, callback)
```

Now the whole operation happens in one iteration.

The nice thing is that in the above expression, the *callback* is used as a mapping function, so if it returns a value, the whole expression returns the array as defined by those return values. But using this is of course optional. For instance, you could create an array with the text contents of the nodes like this:

```
texts = Array.from(nodeList, node => node.textContent)
```

#### Warning

If you use `Array.from` with callback, *and* the node list is a *live* node list (see [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)), *and* you mutate the node list in the callback, then this can have undesired effects. In that case use the two step method where you first turn the node list into an array, and only then perform the callback on its entries.

Answer (score 2):

```
var array=Array.from(nodeList);
//after some time
var array2=Array.from(nodeList);
```

If you compare these Arrays youll see that they are not necessarily equal. NodeLists reflect the change of the DOM, as you copy them the arrays stay static. If you want this behaviour / dont care about youre fine. However *Array.from* is quite new, therefore it isnt understood by older browsers, so it shouldnt be used in productional environments ( if youre not using sth like Babel).